# How to handle unique cell action with mvvm

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I have unique cell in UITableView, which has two buttons. I need to bind these actions to viewModel of controller. I bind view with view model in this way:

```
func attach(wrapper: Attachable<ViewModel>) -> ViewModel {
    self.viewModel = wrapper
    loadViewIfNeeded()
    let viewModel = self.viewModel.bind(bindings: bindings)
    return bind(viewModel: viewModel)
}
```

So, when loadViewIfNeeded() method invokes, I still don't have any cells from data source. That's why I can't create bindings from cell's buttons.

I tried to use delegate and relate on this way, but I think I missed better solution:

```
protocol ProfileActionsViewCellDelegate {
     var addFriendButton: UIButton { get }
}
```

code inside cell

```
func bind(to viewModel: ProfileActionsViewModel) {
    addFriendButton.rx.tap
        .do(onNext: { [unowned self] _ in self.delegate?.addFriendButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside) })
        .debug()
        .subscribe()
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

[mvvm profile example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOV7e.png)